# No resources in GCP Dataproc node to start new SparkSession

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, namenode

I am working on a use case where I have to process a huge amount of data (multiple tables) and I am trying to submit this as a batch job to the Dataproc cluster(PySpark).

My code looks something like this

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def readconfig():
   #code to read a yaml file

def func(filename, tabname):
   sc = SparkContext("local", "First App")
   sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
   spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
   df1= read from file-filename as rdd using sqlcontext
   df2= read from bigquery-tabname as df using spark
   .
   op = intermediate processing
   .
   #caching and unpersisting 2 dfs 
   .
   op.write.csv(write multiple files in gcs bucket)
   sc.stop()
   spark.stop()
   print("one pair of table and file processed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   config= readconfig()
   for i,j in config.items():
      func(i,j):
```

As the file sizes are huge, I am trying to create a separate `SparkSession` for each of the pair of file and table being processed. It works fine and I was able to process a good number of tables. Later I started to receiving warning for memory issues with node and finally an error saying:

> node has insufficient resources. Could not create SparkSession.

Why is this happening when closing a `SparkSession` should relieve the memory of the data from previous iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing a `local` value to a `master` parameter in [`SparkContext` constructor](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#SparkContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.SparkConf-) you are running your application in a local [deployment mode](https://dwgeek.com/spark-mode-of-operation-and-deployment.html) on a single VM (Dataproc master node). That's why you can not process large amount of data in your application.

To fix this issue you should use [parametless `SparkContext()` constructor](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#SparkContext--) that will load parameters from properties configured by Dataproc - in this case your application will run on YARN when you will submit it to Dataproc cluster and will be able to utilize all Dataproc cluster resources/nodes.

Also, you may want to refactor your application to do data processing for all tables in a single `SparkSession` instead of creating per-table `SparkSession` - this should more efficient and scalable if done right.